# How to minimize memory usage for a mostly sleeping thread that may need to be killed

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread in my process that has a few characteristics: 1. it mostly sleeps 2. it only toggles a few booleans; it doesn't interact with any data that could be messed up from abrupt killing (eg, an external database) 3. it may need to be killed at any time from another thread.

A rough approximation is:

```
import time
import threading


class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_bool = True

    def bar(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(60*30)
            self.my_bool = not self.my_bool

foo = Foo()
t = threading.Thread(target=foo.bar)
t.start()
```

According to [this highly voted question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python), I should not kill it abruptly. Does this still apply since it clearly isn't going to be ruining my data collection and cleanup? Specifically, in my kill function, I will manually clean up the processes that interact with the boolean.

I can imagine some other options such as this:

```
import time
import threading
import datetime


class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_bool = True
        self.killed = False

    def bar(self):
        while True and not self.killed:
            next_toggle_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
            print 'next toggle time: ', next_toggle_time
            while datetime.datetime.now() < next_toggle_time and not self.killed:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            self.my_bool = not self.my_bool
```

This doesn't appear to use much memory (0.1% of a MacBook Pro) but it feels kind of ugly and I'm planning to use this on computers with much more limited memory. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm wondering if you considered about using Cron here.

Comment: I've considered it, but my main program has too start and stop `bar` every couple days or so. Using python to set up Cron seems ugly too (but I've never used Cron much). But I'm open to suggestions if you can think of a clean way to do it.

Comment: I'm thinking about a flag (perhaps a file) that your Python program can easily set and the program run by Cron can also easily use the existence of the file to determine if it should proceed.

Comment: @Philip Tzou  I was just typing in a similar answer. That is what I would do.